# A configurable joint created through code doesn't spring [Unity3d]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm trying to add a configurable joint using this code:

```
    public Rigidbody other;
    void Start()
    {
        var currentGrabJoint = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(ConfigurableJoint)) as ConfigurableJoint;
        currentGrabJoint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
        currentGrabJoint.connectedBody = other;
        currentGrabJoint.rotationDriveMode = RotationDriveMode.Slerp;
        var driveJoint = new JointDrive()
        {
            positionSpring = 14000,
            positionDamper = 200
        };
        currentGrabJoint.slerpDrive = driveJoint;
        currentGrabJoint.xDrive = driveJoint;
        currentGrabJoint.yDrive = driveJoint;
        currentGrabJoint.zDrive = driveJoint;
    }
```

It does add the component and sets is values, but the other body just falls and ignores the joint completely.
What is even more weird is that when I set any of the joints motion mode to locked it locks in place.
If I add the joint beforehand with the same values it works as expected.
Any help appreciated.

I've tried adding a configurable joint through code. I expected the joint to work as if added in the editor before start, but instead it did nothing.
I Also tried setting the joints motion modes to fixed (again through code), which surprisngly worked, but it is definetly not what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone was wondering, the joint drive also needs to be initialized with the `maximumForce` parameter. In my case `float.PositiveInfinity`